# Visual Studio execute with debug false - cannot start debugging error

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft Visual Studio (2015 Professional with update 3 on Windows 10 Pro most recently updates applied) execute debug or release

> Studio cannot start debugging because the target  is missing.
>   ... ... check the project properties OutputPath and AssemblyName.

HOWEVER, Studio DID/DOES build/re-build the all targets AND in the solution to the configured folder/s.
In fact, this project has 3 project dependencies and all 4 projects are building to the correct folder and are assembly-named as I would expect.

Project A depends on and properly references B & C.
B depends on and properly references C & D.
C & D do not depend on nor reference any of the other projects.

I've tried removing and re-adding the project references.
Before and after doing so, I wipe out all the obj & bin folders.
F11 and step through the program just fine.
Stop & amend my code.
F11 again and the problem comes right back.

What gives?  How do you find meaningful logging that can be of actual help?

And the funny part? If I 'continue' then Studio advances down my code without error (except for the part about being prompted over and over)

This whole experience just recently started.  I had been doing fine in this project for weeks.

**UPDATE**: I reboot & then deleted and recreated the solution.  Still has the same problem.

Comment: I suggest you are down to deleting and rebuilding the individual .csproj files.

Comment: That can be a lot of work

Comment: user2367083 Start with the simplest one first. Then progress to the next. Testing each rebuild as you go. You might get lucky and only have to do a couple of the easier ones. Also! archive the files you are deleting before you do. Then you might be able to do A-B comparisons to see exactly what may be causing your heartache.

Comment: @user2367083 I GOT LUCKY. I only had to rebuild the smallest of the projects the Project A a simple Windows console app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS does some logging but I've rarely had to resort to it and it can be so verbose that it is its own struggle.  Plus I don't know it includes details specific to these kind of issues in a project.  What it mostly helps with is troubleshooting VS & add-ons.

To me fixing your issue is really a matter of:

1) Delete the obj & bin folders, then rebuild,

2) Reboot,

3) All to often anti-virus will be causing issues overseeing files in the bin folder (but this not so often anymore as it used to be),

4) Rebuild the solution (backup & delete the .sln file),

5) rebuild the individual project files (backup & delete the .*proj file/s),

After that you might have found a VS bug.  Maybe, with HEAVY CONSIDERATION, uninstall & re-install VS.

What probably happens is the GUIDs in the .sln & .proj files get out of alignment.  And that is a but to much to fix manually.

Good luck!